# Re-run Spark jobs on Failure or Abort

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm looking forward for configuration or parameter that auto restart the Spark Jobs in case of any failure submitted via Yarn. I know tasks auto restart on failure. I am *exactly* looking forward for a **YARN or Spark configuration** that would trigger re-run whole job.

Right now if any of our Job abort due to any issue, we have to re start it manually, that causes long data queue to process, as these are designed to work in near real-time.

Current configurations:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2

# Minimum TODOs on a per job basis:
# 1. define name, application jar path, main class, queue and log4j-yarn.properties path
# 2. remove properties not applicable to your Spark version (Spark 1.x vs. Spark 2.x)
# 3. tweak num_executors, executor_memory (+ overhead), and backpressure settings

# the two most important settings:
num_executors=6
executor_memory=32g

# 3-5 cores per executor is a good default balancing HDFS client throughput vs. JVM overhead
# see http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/
executor_cores=2

# backpressure
reciever_minRate=1
receiver_max_rate=10
receiver_initial_rate=10

/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
  --name br1_warid_ccn_sms_production \
  --class com.spark.main\
  --driver-memory 16g \
  --num-executors ${num_executors} --executor-cores ${executor_cores} --executor-memory ${executor_memory} \
  --queue default \
  --files log4j-yarn-warid-br1-ccn-sms.properties \
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn-warid-br1-ccn-sms.properties" \
  --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-yarn-warid-br1-ccn-sms.properties" \
  --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer `# Kryo Serializer is much faster than the default Java Serializer` \
  --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g \
  --conf spark.locality.wait=30 \
  --conf spark.task.maxFailures=8 `# Increase max task failures before failing job (Default: 4)` \
  --conf spark.ui.killEnabled=true `# Prevent killing of stages and corresponding jobs from the Spark UI` \
  --conf spark.logConf=true `# Log Spark Configuration in driver log for troubleshooting` \
`# SPARK STREAMING CONFIGURATION` \
  --conf spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR \
  --conf spark.default.parallelism=32 \
  --conf spark.streaming.blockInterval=200 `# [Optional] Tweak to balance data processing parallelism vs. task scheduling overhead (Default: 200ms)` \
  --conf spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=true `# Prevent data loss on driver recovery` \
  --conf spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=false \
  --conf spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=${receiver_max_rate} `# [Spark 1.x]: Corresponding max rate setting for Direct Kafka Streaming (Default: not set)` \
`# YARN CONFIGURATION` \
  --conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=4096 `# [Optional] Set if --driver-memory < 5GB` \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=4096 `# [Optional] Set if --executor-memory < 10GB` \
  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4 `# Increase max application master attempts (needs to be <= yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts in YARN, which defaults to 2) (Default: yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts)` \
  --conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h `# Attempt counter considers only the last hour (Default: (none))` \
  --conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=$((8 * ${num_executors})) `# Increase max executor failures (Default: max(numExecutors * 2, 3))` \
  --conf spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=1h `# Executor failure counter considers only the last hour` \
  --conf spark.task.maxFailures=8 \
  --conf spark.speculation=false \
/home//runscripts/production.jar
```

Note: There are couple of questions on the subject area, but they do not have accepted answers, or the answer deviate from expected solution.
[Running a Spark application on YARN, without spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276186/running-a-spark-application-on-yarn-without-spark-submit)
[How to configure automatic restart of the application driver on Yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250875/how-to-configure-automatic-restart-of-the-application-driver-on-yarn)

This question explores the possible solutions from the scope of YARN and Spark.

Comment: It looks you covered all possible spark tunables to help you here, main parameter being spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts .. what errors you're getting in driver logs when your spark application dies? Does it try to restart it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought!

Let us call the script file (containing the above script) as `run_spark_job.sh`.

Try adding these statements at the end of the script:

```
return_code=$?

if [[ ${return_code} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Job failed"
    exit ${return_code}
fi

echo "Job succeeded"
exit 0
```

Let us have another script file `spark_job_runner.sh`, from where we call the above script.
For example,

```
./run_spark_job.sh
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
    ./run_spark_job.sh
done
```

**YARN-based approaches:**
Update 1:  This link will be a good read.  It discusses YARN REST API to submit and track: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/28070/starting-spark-jobs-directly-via-yarn-rest-api.html

Update 2: This link shows how to submit spark application to YARN environment using Java: https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/misc/how-to-submit-spark-job-to-yarn-from-java-code.md

**Spark-based programmatic approach:**

[How to use the programmatic spark submit capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37243481/how-to-use-the-programmatic-spark-submit-capability)

**Spark based configuration approach for YARN:**

The *only* spark parameter on YARN mode for restarting is `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts` and it should not exceed the YARN resource manager parameter `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts`

Excerpt from the official documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

> The maximum number of attempts that will be made to submit the
>   application.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm looking forward for clean way at Yarn or Spark level.

Answer (score 1):

In yarn mode you can set 
yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts which is default 2 to re-run the failed job, you can increase as many time you want. Or you can use spark's spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts configuration for same.

Comment: yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts ----The maximum number of attempts that will be made to submit the application. It should be no larger than the global number of max attempts in the YARN configuration. It won't retry the failed ones.